# Golf mk4 1.6 gearboxes?

Tags: vw, transmission, golf

Im new to this forum so i dont really know if this topic has already been opened... anyway i have a golf mk4 1.6 16v and my reverse gear was making clunking noises...so long story short the only gearbox that a mechanic could find was a diesel gearbox  and i needed the car fast so he instaled it but he didnt told me that the car will have long/short gears (i dont know which are tje long or short im a noob when it comes to this things...) and the speedo gauges dont work right anymore... i mean it wasnt the fastestes car in the world but now is slow as f* when on highways..
So i was wondering which gearbox other than petrol 1.6 will fit my engine because here im Slovenia is a little hard to find this perticular gearbox... the engine is 1.6 16v AUS petrol year 2000. Thanks for replys

Comment: I was looking at the wikipedia and found this: 1.6L I4 16v 77kW (AUS/AZD/ATN/BCB).. do they all fit or... maybe another bramd maybe?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Hopefully someone will have the information for you!

Comment: Is this a manual or automatic transmission? I'm assuming manual, but hate to assume anything.

Comment: If the speedometer doesn't work correctly, are you using the information from the speedometer as your reference for being slow? I suspect you're using adjacent traffic as your reference, but you should get an accurate indication of your speed. GPS on a phone with speed readout?

Comment: So sory for not saying its a manual:) i was using gps for some time i even installed an iphone in my car just for that and connected it to the car electric to charg it only when i drive.. then the phone stoped working and now i memorized how fast i am going by looking at clocks... when im going 130km/h on clocks im actualy going 145km/h... but it changes from gear to gear so i cant actualy use any speeso corector kit

Comment: By slow i meant elwhen i push the gas padel it takes forever to go from 110 to 130km/h... with original gearbox there was a big diference:)

Comment: Your best bet is to get the correct 1.6 gearbox... you may find one on ebay - even purchasing a complete accident damaged car may be an option...

Comment: I had an '00 1.6 8v AKL engined model with a DUU type 5 speed gearbox. I believe the big difference is the linkage, mine was solid, later models were cable driven so you'd need to make sure you get the right linkage.They were awful gearboxes though... I also recall the speedo is driven/read from the box so that would explain why the clocks aren't correct.